# "make more orders for pencils" vs "make an order for more pencils"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In practicing sentence writing, i want to write a sentence meaning what a shop will do when the demand for pencils rises, assuming the shop is eager to meet the increased demand. To my mind, following two phrases are possible.

> "make more orders for pencils" vs "make an order for more pencils"

But i'm not sure which one a native would use. (maybe neither of them)

Please tell me which phrase is better and correct grammatically and semantically.

Comment: It's entirely down to whether the shopkeeper is thinking about a *single* order (for a large number of pencils) that he needs to make, so he has enough pencils to meet the expected demand. Or if he's just thinking he'll need to order pencils (in smaller amounts at a time) *more often* in future. In either case, he's going to end up with more pencils, bought with one or more orders.

Comment: It would be silly to place 50 orders for 10 pencils if you want 500 pencils, and it is possible to make a single order for that quantity.

Comment: He might be placing several orders for different types of pencil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One doesn't **make** orders, but **place** them.

> "Place an order for more pencils"

or, if one's supplies are running low,

> "Restock pencils."

Comment: We can certainly **make** orders where I come from (UK). From  [liturgical vestments](https://vestment.co.uk/How-to-make-an-order-chelp-eng-2.html) via [fingernail products](https://www.mynailshop.co.uk/how-to-make-an-order/) to [dog food](https://www.petshop.co.uk/faq)

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHarvey, I didn't know that.

Comment: Of course, we can also place orders, or submit them.